# Untyped functions that return tables

Tags: postgresql, functions, datatypes, plpgsql

I would like to write a PostgreSQL stored function that essentially behaves like the stored procedures I know and love from MSSQL and MySQL where I can just wrap a query that takes no parameters and have it return that resultset without having to specify the format of the output and change that definition every time I update the query. Is this even possible in PostgreSQL ?

I've tried the following using PostgreSQL 9.2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
RETURNS SETOF record
```

Which gives me the following error:

> ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"

I've also tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
RETURNS table ()
```

but apparently that's invalid syntax.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: Just to clarify: `Postgres` is an "officially" accepted abbreviation for `PostgreSQL`. [Consider the second link in the info page](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql/info). Personally I *do* prefer `PostgreSQL` in the title ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding. A function like this is perfectly valid:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
 RETURNS SETOF record AS
$func$
VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4);  -- 2 rows with 2 integer columns
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

However, since it returns anonymous records, you are required to provide a **column definition list with every *call*** , just like the error message told you. SQL demands to know what to expect from a function up front. The call would work like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test() AS f(a int, b int);
```

Functions returning anonymous records have their uses. I try to avoid them mostly, because the call is rather unwieldy. Depending on your exact requirements, there are a couple of ways around it. I wrote a [comprehensive answer for that on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557) recently.

Comment: Hm, that's frustrating. I've never written a column definition list either in a stored procedure definition or call in either MSSQL or MySQL and it's always worked fine.

Comment: @SWrobel: Define a well known return type and you don't need a column definition list. It's all in the linked answer.